# Spring Scheduled Task Overlapping In Multiple Thread Pools

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have a Spring scheduled task running every hour that needs to be run without overlapping.
However I'm running into an issue where the task is being started twice, but in separate thread pools.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    // ...

    @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(final ScheduledTaskRegistrar scheduledTaskRegistrar) {
        scheduledTaskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }
}
```

**Job Class**

```
@Service
public class JobClass {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3600000)
    public void doJob() {
        LOG.debug("Start Task");
    }
}
```

**Log Output**

```
DEBUG 2016-09-26 15:49:08,874 [pool-2-thread-1][] JobClass - Start Task
DEBUG 2016-09-26 15:49:10,249 [pool-1-thread-1][] JobClass - Start Task
```

Is there any way to enforce that only one thread pool is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after coming back the next day, I was able to figure this out relatively quickly. It ended up being an issue with me copy/pasting the web xml from another application.

my web xml contained the below:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    version="2.5">

    <!-- Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.AppConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Context Loader -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.AppConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

So what is happening, is that the executor isn't creating a thread in multiple pools. I was creating two contexts that are executing the scheduled task. I was able to fix this by removing the configuration for the Dispatcher Servlet configuration (I didn't need it for this application). For anyone that might stumble across the same issue that does need the dispatcher servlet, there should be two separate configuration classes, one for the spring context, and one for the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your executor like this:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
}
```

I hope that it will save your time!

Comment: From the Executor documentation for `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`: "Unlike the otherwise equivalent `newScheduledThreadPool(1)` the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads." So the result is the same except my current code guarantees no additional Threads. I already tried your example during my own tests to get this to work and received the same result.